# Multiple inheritance ambiguities with minimal code clutter

Tags: c++, c++11

I have two interfaces: `IFace2` derives from `IFace`

```cpp
class IFace
{
public:
    virtual ~IFace() = default;

    virtual void doit() = 0;
};

class IFace2 : public IFace
{
public:
    virtual void doit2() = 0;
};
```

I am trying reduce code clutter that is required by the implementations. In `IFace2Impl` I would like to use the same implementation from `IFaceImpl`. Unfortunately, that forces me to  resolve ambiguity and I need to override every function in `IFace2Impl`:

```cpp
class IFaceImpl : public IFace
{
public:
    void doit() override
    {
    }
};

class IFace2Impl : public IFaceImpl, IFace2
{
public:
    using IFaceImpl::doit; // not resolving ambiguity

    void doit2() override
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    IFace2Impl impl;
}
```

When I try to compile this code, the compiler gives me an error message:

```
<source>(36): error C2259: 'IFace2Impl': cannot instantiate abstract class
<source>(24): note: see declaration of 'IFace2Impl'
<source>(36): note: due to following members:
<source>(36): note: 'void IFace::doit(void)': is abstract
<source>(6): note: see declaration of 'IFace::doit'
```

https://godbolt.org/z/91M1j8bv3

For each virtual function I have to provide full definition:

```
class IFace2Impl : public IFaceImpl, IFace2
{
public:
    void doit() 
    { 
        IFaceImpl::doit(); 
    }

    void doit2() override
    {
    }
};
```

Is there a way to handle this more elegantly? When number of interface method grows, the more ambiguities I have to resolve.

Comment: Thanks for being patient and helping me to make my question clear, I appreciate it a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Virtual inheriance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) might help, so `IFaceImpl` would have only one `IFace` instead of 2:

```
class IFace
{
public:
    virtual ~IFace() = default;

    virtual void doit() = 0;
};

class IFace2 : public virtual IFace
{
public:
    virtual void doit2() = 0;
};

class IFaceImpl : public virtual IFace
{
public:
    void doit() override {}
};

class IFace2Impl :
    public IFaceImpl,
    public virtual IFace2 // virtual not required here, but would be with IFace3Impl...
{
public:
    void doit2() override {}
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9Yefqavfr)